# Regular Expressions: Positive and Negative Lookahead Solution

Tags: javascript, regex

I was doing Freecodecamp RegEx challange, which's about:

> Use lookaheads in the pwRegex to match passwords that are greater than 5 characters long, do not begin with numbers, and have two consecutive digits

So far the solution I found passed all the tests was:

```
/^[a-z](?=\w{5,})(?=.*\d{2}\.)/i
```

However, when I tried

```
/^[a-z](?=\w{5,})(?=\D*\d{2,}\D*)/i
```

I failed the test trying to match `astr1on11aut` (but passed with `astr11on1aut`). So can someone help me explaining how `?=\D*\d{2,}\D*` failed this test?

Comment: Because the pattern `(?=\D*\d{2,}\D*)`  tries to assert 2 digits, and `astr1on11aut` contains first 1 digit, and then 2 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to lookahead usage in regex, rememeber to anchor them all at the start of the pattern. See [Lookarounds (Usually) Want to be Anchored](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#anchor). This will help you avoid a lot of issues when dealing with password regexps.

Now, let's see what requirements you have:

- "are greater than 5 characters long" => `(?=.{6})` (it requires any 6 chars other than lien break chars immediately to the right of the current location)
- "do not begin with numbers" => `(?!\d)` (no digit allowed immediately to the right)
- `have two consecutive digits` => `(?=.*\d{2})` (any two digit chunk of text is required after any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, immediately to the right of the current location).

So, what you may use is

```
^(?!\d)(?=.{6})(?=.*\d{2})
```

Note the most expensive part is placed at the end of the pattern so that it could fail quicker if the input is non-matching.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U0zlum/1).

Comment: Thank you, this solution is so much more understandable and simpler than mine.

Answer (score 3):

## Failed for the `\d{2,}`

Then let's have a look at the regexp match process

```js
/^[a-z](?=\w{5,})
```

means start with [a-z], the length is at least 6, no problem.

```
(?=\D*\d{2,}\D*)
```

means the first letter should be followed by these parts:

```
[0 or more no-digit][2 or more digits][0 or more no-digits]
```

and lets have a look at the test case

```js
astr1on11aut
// ^[a-z] match "a"
// length matchs
// [0 or more no-digit]: "str"
// d{2,} failed: only 1 digit
```

the `?=` position lookahead means exact followed by.

---

The first regular expression is wrong, it should be

```js
/^[a-z](?=\w{5,})(?=.*\d{2}.*)/i
```

Comment: Yeah, I was confuse about why `(?=\D*\d{2,}\D*)` did not check `..n11a..` . The fourth bird gave clear explanation about that. I was new to regex ==

Comment: Btw, thank you for the error in the last group in the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

> So can someone help me explaining how `(?=\D*\d{2,}\D*)` failed this
> test?

Using `\D` matches any char except a digit, so from the start of the string you can not pass single digit to get to the 2 digits.

**Explanation**

```
astr1on11aut                            astr11on1aut
    ^                                       ^^
    Can not pass 1 before reaching 11       Can match 2 digits first
```

**Note**

- the expression could be shortened to `(?=\D*\d{2})` as it does not matter if there are 2, 3 or more because 2 is the minimum and the `\D*` after is is optional.
- the first expression `^[a-z](?=\w{5,})(?=.*\d{2}\.)` can not match the example data because it expects to match a `.` literally after 2 digits.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But for `(?=\D*\d{2,}\D*)` , I have tested with the sample data and this pattern passed the test, but it will surely fail with the sample `astr1on11` as you pointed out the fact about `.` in the end of the pattern.

Comment: @MinhNguyễn The note is only about how that part could be shortened if you want to use a pattern like that in the future.